# Select query having count and variable

Tags: sql-server, select, count

I have a table like the one below.

[image: Main Table]

I need to form a select query. I'm going to pass a `RefID` like

```
SELECT SNo  FROM Register WHERE RefID = 1
```

And beside the `SNo` in the Statement, I need to have another column which contains the total `COUNT` of `refID` belonging to that `SNo`. For example:

[image: Required Output]

The Precise Question as @JNK Specified:

Show me all the Sno values with a RefID of 1, and for each Sno show me also a count of how many times that Sno value is itself used as a RefID anywhere else in the table.

Comment: Why are any of these zero? I think you need to explain your logic a little better.

Comment: Because the `SNo 5` is not there in RefID column. and Since `Sno 2` is referenced `1` time in `RefID`, the `Cnt` of `Sno 2` in Output is `1`.

Comment: Once check the First Table. In that the RefID contains Value-2 1 time. The Value-2 is the Serial No of the same Table and since SNo 5 is not Present as the RefID in the First Table the Cnt is 0 in the output Table. In the Output, the cnt column is the count of the RefID s. ie If there is a SNo 1 in the Output, The Cnt would be 5. Because, since the SNo 5 is Used 5 times as RefID in the First Table. Ok?

Comment: I think it's because he is using 1 as his refid in the parameter.

Comment: I'm so sorry that I'm not able to explain my problem in the way you understand. @JNK is Right that I'm using 1 as RefID in the Parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, this should get it for you.  I believe what you are saying is:

> Show me all the `Sno` values with a `RefID` of 1, and for each `Sno`
>   show me also a count of how many times that `Sno` value is itself used
>   as a `RefID` anywhere else in the table.

I'm sure this can be tweaked but it gives what you are after.

```
SELECT
  SNo,
  COALESCE(MAX(sub.CT), 0)
FROM
  dbo.MyTable T
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT RefID, COUNT(*) as CT
   FROM dbo.MyTable
   GROUP BY RefID) Sub
    ON Sub.RefID = T.Sno 
WHERE
  T.RefId = 1
GROUP BY Sno
```

[There's a fiddle here with an example.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b3cd2/12)

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use an inline subquery ?

```
select A.SNo,
       (select count(*) from Register B where B.Sno = A.Sno) as Cnt
from Register A
where A.RefId = 1
```